# Strange turtle error when threading functions

Tags: python, multithreading, function, turtle-graphics

When I run a script that I made, I get a very strange error. I am threading two functions, moving(), and moveWithMouse(). The relevant code is posted here:

```
def moving():

# Clearing the canvas and hiding the turtle for the next iteration of moving()
turtle.clear()
turtle.hideturtle()

# Drawing all of the circles
for i in range(len(xCoordinate)):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(xCoordinate[i], yCoordinate[i])
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.fillcolor(color[i][0], color[i][1], color[i][2])
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(10)      
    turtle.end_fill()
    xCoordinate[i] += speed1[i]
    yCoordinate[i] += speed2[i] 
    turtle.update()
    turtle.ontimer(moving, 10)
```

Code for the next function:

```
def moveWithMouse():
    while True:
    user = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    mousepos = [user[0]-520,-1*(user[1])+ 415]
    turtle.goto(mousepos)
    turtle.onclick(turtle.pendown())
```

Then I thread both of these functions like so:

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = moving).start()
    Thread(target = moveWithMouse).start()
```

And it will give me this error (It's very long, but I still think posting all of it is necessary):

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\threading.py", line 736, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\threading.py", line 689, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\Circles with Collision Detection.py", line 57, in moving
    turtle.circle(10)
  File "<string>", line 1, in circle
  File "C:\Python32\lib\turtle.py", line 1991, in circle
    self._go(l)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\turtle.py", line 1605, in _go
    self._goto(ende)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\turtle.py", line 3159, in _goto
    screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
  File "C:\Python32\lib\turtle.py", line 755, in _pointlist
    cl = self.cv.coords(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in coords
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2162, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2160, in <listcomp>
    return [getdouble(x) for x in
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'coords'

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\threading.py", line 736, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\threading.py", line 689, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\Circles with Collision Detection.py", line 128, in moveWithMouse
    turtle.goto(mousepos)
  File "<string>", line 1, in goto
  File "C:\Python32\lib\turtle.py", line 1774, in goto
    self._goto(Vec2D(*x))
  File "C:\Python32\lib\turtle.py", line 3159, in _goto
    screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
  File "C:\Python32\lib\turtle.py", line 755, in _pointlist
    cl = self.cv.coords(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in coords
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2162, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: ambiguous option "": must be addtag, bbox, bind, canvasx, canvasy, cget, configure, coords, create, dchars, delete, dtag, find, focus, gettags, icursor, index, insert, itemcget, itemconfigure, lower, move, postscript, raise, scale, scan, select, type, xview, or yview
```

It appears that it's saying there's a problem with the goto statements in both functions. Both these function work when I don't thread them, but threaded, they seem to give this very strange error. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

The `turtle` module is based on `Tkinter`. `Tkinter` was designed to be single-threaded. That is, to avoid errors, all Tkinter calls must originate from the same thread.

Both `moving` and `moveWithMouse` are calling `turtle` commands.
So you can not spawn two threads to run these functions.

Comment: Thank you! This doesn't really help the problem, but at least it shows why the problem is there.

Comment: Are you trying to draw a circle where the user clicks the mouse? In that case, instead of calling `turtle` commands inside `moveWithMouse`, just modify  `xCoordinate` and `yCoordinate` and let `moving` do all the drawing.

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to generate another ball every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Python's turtle module doesn't claim to be thread-safe (see [bug 1702036](http://bugs.python.org/issue1702036)). So you can't assume that moving two turtles around will work as expected (which is what you're doing: in both threads you're moving the turtle for drawing).